# generic scoring module using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scoring

Hi I'm trying to develop a generic scoring module for grading students based on variety of attributes. I'm trying to develop a generic method using python pandas
Input: 
An input data frame with student ID and UG Major and attributes for scoring (I called df_input)
An input ref. data frame that contains scoring params

Process: Based on the variable type, developing a process to calculate scores for each attribute

Output: Input data frame with added cols that capture the attribute score
Example:

df_input

+

```
------------+-----------+----+------------+-----+------+
| STUDENT_ID | UG_MAJOR  | C1 |     C2     | C3  |  C4  |
+------------+-----------+----+------------+-----+------+
|        123 | MATH      | A  | 8000-10000 | 12% | 9000 |
|        234 | ALL_OTHER | B  | 1500-2000  | 10% | 1500 |
|        345 | ALL_OTHER | A  | 2800-3000  | 8%  | 2300 |
|        456 | ALL_OTHER | A  | 8000-10000 | 12% | 3200 |
|        980 | ALL_OTHER | C  | 1000-2500  | 15% | 2700 |
+------------+-----------+----+------------+-----+------+
```

df_ref
+

```
---------+---------+---------+
| REF_COL | REF_VAL | REF_SCR |
+---------+---------+---------+
| C1      | A       |      10 |
| C1      | B       |      20 |
| C1      | C       |      30 |
| C1      | NULL    |       0 |
| C1      | MISSING |       0 |
| C1      | A       |      20 |
| C1      | B       |      30 |
| C1      | C       |      40 |
| C1      | NULL    |      10 |
| C1      | MISSING |      10 |
| C2      | <1000   |       0 |
| C2      | >1000   |      20 |
| C2      | >7000   |      30 |
| C2      | >9500   |      40 |
| C2      | MISSING |       0 |
| C2      | NULL    |       0 |
| C3      | <3%     |       5 |
| C3      | >3%     |      10 |
| C3      | >5%     |     100 |
| C3      | >7%     |     200 |
| C3      | >10%    |     300 |
| C3      | NULL    |       0 |
| C3      | MISSING |       0 |
| C4      | <5000   |      10 |
| C4      | >5000   |      20 |
| C4      | >10000  |      30 |
| C4      | >15000  |      40 |
+---------+---------+---------+

+------------+-----------+----+------------+-----+------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| Req.Output |           |    |            |     |      |        |        |        |         |
+------------+-----------+----+------------+-----+------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| STUDENT_ID | UG_MAJOR  | C1 | C2         | C3  | C4   | C1_SCR | C2_SCR | C3_SCR | TOT_SCR |
| 123        | MATH      | A  | 8000-10000 | 12% | 9000 |        |        |        |         |
| 234        | ALL_OTHER | B  | 1500-2000  | 10% | 1500 |        |        |        |         |
| 345        | ALL_OTHER | A  | 2800-3000  | 8%  | 2300 |        |        |        |         |
| 456        | ALL_OTHER | A  | 8000-10000 | 12% | 3200 |        |        |        |         |
| 980        | ALL_OTHER | C  | 1000-2500  | 15% | 2700 |        |        |        |         |
+------------+-----------+----+------------+-----+------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```

I want to see if any thing like a function be developed to accomplish this

Thank you
Pari

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read the required help documentation, especially http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Calculating scores for attributes sounds like a machine learning process of some sort.  Have you researched those?  Or did you just want something to calculate grade percentages?  That's simple algebra.  In either case, you need to provide the code you wrote, the output you got, and a description of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to store a collection of rules in `df_ref` that are to be applied to `df_input` to generate scores. While this certainly can be done, you should make sure that your rules are well defined. This would also guide you in writing the corresponding scoring function.

For instance, suppose one of the students gets a value of `10000` in column `C3`. `10000` is larger than `1000`, `7000` and `9500`. This means that the score is ambiguous. Suppose you want to choose the highest of all scores from this particular column. Then, you need another table specifying the choice rule for each column when multiple scores are selected.

Second, you should think about the type of Python variable stored in 'REF_VAL' column. If `>7000` is a string, you would have to do extra work to determine the score. Consider storing this as `7000` instead and specifying comparison operator elsewhere.

Finally, looking at your current rules, there seems to be a pattern. Each score is associated with `NULL`, `MISSING` or a range cutoff. This can be captured as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import dropwhile

# stores values and scores for special values and cutoff values
sample_range_rule = {
    'MISSING' : 0,
    'NULL'    : 0,
    'VALS'    : [
        (0, 0),
        (10, 50),
        (70, 75),
        (90, 100),
        (100, 100)
    ]
}

# takes a dict with rules and produces a scoring function
def getScoringFunction(range_rule):
    def score(val):
        if val == 'MISSING':
            return range_rule['MISSING']
        elif val == 'NULL':
            return range_rule['NULL']
        else:
            return dropwhile(lambda (cutoff, score): cutoff < val,
                range_rule['VALS']).next()[1]
    return score

sample_scoring_function = getScoringFunction(sample_range_rule)

for test_value in ['MISSING', 'NULL', 0, 12, 55, 66, 99]:
    print 'Input', test_value,
    print 'Output', sample_scoring_function(test_value)
```

After you have a dict specifying a rule for every column, you can do the following:

`df['Ck_SCR'] = df['Ck'].apply(getScoringFunction(Ck_dct))`

Converting pandas DataFrame with two columns to a dict of this form should not be to difficult.